# In Titanium JS, when setting rightNavButtons, the buttons only work for the first 4 taps

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-mobile

In my app for iOS I've used the `rightNavButtons` property of a window to add two buttons in the top right.

However, the click events on these buttons only work for the first 4 taps and then nothing happens when you click on them. What is going on? Could this be a bug with Titanium?

Here is my code:

*Titanium SDK version: 3.4.0.v20140916181713*

*Alloy version: 1.5.1*

**Controller - index.js:**

```
var addButton = Ti.UI.createButton({ systemButton: Ti.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.ADD });
var searchButton = Ti.UI.createButton({ systemButton: Ti.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.SEARCH });

addButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log("ADD was clicked!");
});

searchButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log("SEARCH was clicked!");
});

$.win.setRightNavButtons([searchButton, addButton]);

$.index.open();
```

**View - index.xml**

```
<Alloy>
    <TabGroup>
        <Tab title="Tab 1" icon="KS_nav_ui.png">
            <Window id="win" title="Tab 1">
                <Label>I am Window 1</Label>
            </Window>
        </Tab>
        <Tab title="Tab 2" icon="KS_nav_views.png">
            <Window title="Tab 2">
                <Label>I am Window 2</Label>
            </Window>
        </Tab>
    </TabGroup>
</Alloy>
```

Comment: I tested your exact code  with 3.4.0.GA / Alloy 1.5.0 on iOS8 simulator and the click listeners weren't working at all for me :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested this code and it should work for you

```
  <Tab title="Tab 1" icon="KS_nav_ui.png">
        <Window id="win" title="Tab 1">
           <RightNavButtons platform=ios>
             <Button systemButton="Ti.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.ADD" onClick="addHandler" />
             <Button systemButton="Ti.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.SEARCH" onClick="searchHandler" />
           </RightNavButtons>
           <Label>I am Window 1</Label>
        </Window>
    </Tab>
```

Comment: buttons or labels could work basically anything that is a view object will work

Answer (score 2):

**Found a workaround!**

I avoid the <RightNavButton**s**>, which can contain more than one view.

Instead I use <RightNavButton> which can contain only one child view.

To add still add two buttons to my navbar, I nested the buttons in the view container (the single child of the <RightNavButton>.

```
<RightNavButton>
    <View>
        <Button class="i i-heart nav-button" id="favorite" onClick="toggleFavorite" right="0" />
        <Button class="i i-share nav-button" id="share" right="32" />
    </View>
</RightNavButton>
```

No issues anymore. Both onClick events of the <Button> childs inside the View container are fired.

Answer (score 1):

When I tried to execute your code, the event listeners weren't being called at all for me on 3.4.0.GA / Alloy 1.5.0 and iOS8 Simulator.

However, when I put the RightNavButton inside the XML as below, it worked fine and the event listener was called every time I clicked on it.  Looks like a bug to me...

```
<Tab title="Tab 1" icon="KS_nav_ui.png">
    <Window id="win" title="Tab 1">
       <RightNavButton platform=ios>
         <Button systemButton="Ti.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.ADD" onClick="closeWindow" />
       </RightNavButton>
       <Label>I am Window 1</Label>
    </Window>
</Tab>
```

Comment: Can you do the same for more than one right nav button using `RightNavButtons`?

Comment: yup see Aaron's answer